# How can I align widths of first column in a list of rows using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am making a layout where a column contains up to 5 rows. Each row has three columns and I would like to have the width of the first column of each row be completely equal.

The first column in each row always takes up as much size as the text it contains, the size of the column doesn't scale to match the size of the biggest column in the list of rows.

Each row item:

```
fun GetRowItem(firstColumnText: String, secondColumnText: String, thirdColumnText: String) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 4.dp, end = 4.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 4.dp),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = firstColumnText
            )
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 4.dp),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = secondColumnText
            )
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 4.dp),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = thirdColumnText
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a parent that arranges the rows something like this:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp) {
    GetRowItem(firstColumnText = "short", secondColumnText = "something", thirdColumnText = "something")
    GetRowItem(firstColumnText = "Realy long ee", secondColumnText = "something", thirdColumnText = "something")
    GetRowItem(firstColumnText = "1", secondColumnText = "something", thirdColumnText = "something")
}
```

The output of this is not what I am looking for and I am struggling to see how to align the columns in each row item. It looks like `InstrisicSize` might be an option here, but I'm not sure how to get the max size of an arbitrary column in the list of rows and apply it to each column. The image below shows what I am getting versus what I am expecting. I only want to align the first columns, the rest don't matter.

[image: expected vs actual]

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to achieve this would be to give each of the columns the same [weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)).

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)){
 // text
}
```

Comment: This would make all three columns take up the same amount of space though correct? I only want the first column widths to be equal, as the second column might just end up being a divider or something similar. The divider would then take up 1/3 of the full width, which doesn't work.

Comment: @Citut What happens if you only apply the weight to the first column in each row and ignore the other columns?

Comment: That gets it closer, but the column width of the 1st column is super wide. They are the same size, but they aren't constrained to the max size of the biggest column.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to solve your issue

**Get Row Item**

```
@Composable
fun GetRowItem(firstColumnText: String, secondColumnText: String, thirdColumnText: String, width: State<Int>, widthCallback: (Int) -> Unit) {

    val widthInDp = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        width.value.toDp()
    }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 4.dp, end = 4.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 4.dp),
        ) {
            if (widthInDp == 0.dp) {
                Text(
                    text = firstColumnText,
                    modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                        widthCallback(it.size.width)
                    }
                )
            }else {
                Text(
                    text = firstColumnText,
                    modifier = Modifier.width(width = widthInDp)
                )
            }
        }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 4.dp),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = secondColumnText
            )
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 4.dp),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = thirdColumnText
            )
        }
    }

}
```

**Parent code that holds the row**

```
           Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    val width = remember {
                        mutableStateOf(0)
                    }
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                            GetRowItem(firstColumnText = "short", secondColumnText = "something", thirdColumnText = "something", width = width) {
                                if (it > width.value) {
                                    width.value = it
                                }
                            }
                            GetRowItem(firstColumnText = "Realy long ee", secondColumnText = "something", thirdColumnText = "something", width = width) {
                                if (it > width.value) {
                                    width.value = it
                                }
                            }
                            GetRowItem(firstColumnText = "1", secondColumnText = "something", thirdColumnText = "something", width = width) {
                                if (it > width.value) {
                                    width.value = it
                                }
                            }
                        
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'have added `surface` and modified `column` to `fillMaxSize()` so you can test this

Answer (score 0):

maybe it could help

```
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
        ) {

        }
```

if you want the center column to be wider than the left and right column you can set the weight of the center column 2 and left and right 1, or you can set the width of columns for example to 100 dp or 200 dp, and set **horizontalArrangement** of your row to **Arrangement.SpaceBetween**  to have some margin around the columns